# Html Horizontal alignment prob

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this Html code to align in a horizontal like display form. It might have some un-neccessary id's,classes,etc.
Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```css
ul.head {
  text-transform: Capitalize;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  font: italic bold 20px/60px"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.H2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1><p id="p1"><em>ENVY</p></em></h1>
<img id="img1" src="envy.jpg" width="150" height="113">
</ul>
<!--End of HEADING-->
<ul class="head">
  <!--Start of top tabs/drop down menu-->
  <h2>
   <li id="H2"><a href="#"><ul id="T1" >New york</ul></a>
   <a href="#"><ul id="T2" >Miami</ul></a>
   <a href="#"><ul id="T3" >Boston</ul></a></li>
  </h2> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You want to display your list horizontally or center the content ?

Comment: have no idea then check this link http://jsfiddle.net/2u1vu4jf/1/

Comment: I edited your code into a code snippet so that it can be run directly on this page.

Comment: Your html markup is completely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you have some syntax error in your code :

```
.H2{ display: inline; }
```

you can't target an `h2` with the `DOT` , dot's only to target classes

`li's` inside an `h1` you can ,but it's highly recommended that you use one only `h1` tag for each page to set main title , you can use a `div` to structure your page element instead

i added this to your css , hope that this is what you need :

```
   .newnew{

    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
        }


ul li a { display: inline-block; padding: 10px; font-size: 13px;}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ywgtpkL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

hello dear please check this link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2u1vu4jf/)

#### CSS

```
ul.head{
     text-transform: Capitalize;
     word-spacing: 10px;
     font: italic bold 20px/60px "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     }
li ul{
    display: inline;}
```